# Simulation of gaussian process

Tags: r, normal-distribution, simulation, gaussian-process

Let $Z=Z_1,\dots Z_N$ a stationary  gaussian process with $\mathbb E(Z_1)=0$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(Z_1,Z_n)=\frac1n\, \forall n=1,\dots N$.
I want to simulate a sample $(Z_1,\dots,Z_{50})$ , how can I do this with R?

Comment: $$\Sigma = \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^\top$$ is singular, so... good luck.

Comment: What do you want the covariances among $Z_2, \ldots, Z_{50}$ to be?  Is this supposed to be a stationary process?  (@Sycorax: why would a singular covariance matrix be a problem?)

Comment: @whuber Equations for the posterior predictive means and variances involve inversion of the covariance matrix for the sample data.

Comment: @whuber yes it should be a stationary process, I edited the question

Comment: Let me amplify the comment made by @Sycorax, then.  Your requirement specifies that all the $Z_i$ are perfectly correlated with the same mean, so just generate $Z_1$ and set $Z_2=Z_3=\cdots=Z_N=Z_1$!  Is this really what you intend?

Comment: @whuber but then for example $cov (X_1,X_2)=cov (X_1,X_3)$ or? And I need $cov (X_1,X_2)=  1/2 \, cov (X_1,X_3)=1/3$

Comment: Now I see, thank you!  The example you just gave shows how I misread the formula.